# How to create correct RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I tried many combinations to create right regex, but I failed.

I want to read this, input:

```
[@Homer Jay Simpson](id:homer) is a good guy.
```

and get

```
Array (
   [0] => "[@Homer Jay Simpson](id:homer)",
   [1] => "Homer Jay Simpson",
   [2] => "homer"
)
```

thanks!

Comment: I am not sure @rika that regex is a good option better try to explode a string by brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little bit of fiddling, this regex will work for you:

```
\[@([^\]]+)\]\(id:([^)]+)\)
```

Used like:

```
$str = "[@Homer Jay Simpson](id:homer) is a good guy.";
preg_match('#\[@([^\]]+)\]\(id:([^)]+)\)#', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [@Homer Jay Simpson](id:homer)
    [1] => Homer Jay Simpson
    [2] => homer
)
```

---

A tip when creating regex patterns, start small and build onto the ends of it. I started with just matching the inside of the square brackets `\[@([^\]]+)\]` then pieced on the rest of it. Full log [here](https://pastebin.com/aMds76kN)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lAg

```
preg_match("/\[\@(.*?)\]\(id:(.*?)\)/", $str, $matches);
Var_dump($matches);
```

This will capture what it between brackets `[]` and `()`.
`\` makes reges read signs as literal.
`.*?` means lazy capture anything if any length.